# Micro Javascript templates not rendering correct in IE, but works fine without javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

This is a bit of an odd issue I'm having. I've been using John Resig' micro-templates for a meeting minutes application, and it seemed to work well, but lately I've been having an issue.

Basically the application fetches some JSON from an ajax call, and then uses the templating engine to generate a table with various actions like so:

[image: actions display]

This works fine, its a little slow in IE (javascript rendering) but it works. However randomly I'll get a stuff up in the display:

[image: ie stuff up]

notice the gap there, its pushed it out wide, also, its made the rest of the rows squish up. I've tried every CSS/HTML trick I can think of to try and get IE to render it properly, but I'm out of ideas (any suggestions would be great!) . I'm using JQuery Sortable so you can drag each of those rows around, I noticed that when you drag it and place it again, it displays correctly. It's as if it thinks theres an extra TD there, when there isn't.

So I opened the IE developer tools and copied the inner HTML of the HTML element. Pasted this into a HTML file and put it on the server, turned off the JS so it wouldn't reload the elements and ran the page. It displays perfectly, just as in my first image.

So I'm confused as to why IE will render the page fine if the HTML is present from the start, but the templating engine causes odd stuff ups.

I'll probably look at rendering that part of the HTML on the server, and only use the templating where I need to. But has anyone come across this sort of issue before? is there any trick I can do to make it render it as it should?

Answer (score 1):

we had similar problem in our company and our designer solved it. Solution was in concatenating  tags one after another without spaces and/or without new line. Code is not looking great after that but still solves problem. 
Thanks, 
Nikola